# How to tell which MDB is listening on which port

Tags: jms, message-driven-bean, websphere-6.1

From the WAS admin console, is there an easy way to check which MDB is listening on which listener port? I cannot open up the ear and check the ibm-ejb-jar-bnd.xml file because I do not have access on the machine itself, just the WAS console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in WAS console select your enterprise application that has MDB and click "Message Driven Bean listener bindings" link there ("Enterprise Java Bean Properties" section). 
you can both view and change listener bindings there once application is deployed.

Comment: Thanks. But that option "Message Driven Bean listener bindings" is not present in WAS 6.1

Comment: check whether selected application has MDB - this option is not present otherwise.

Comment: yes it has 3 MDBs and 3 listener ports. Maybe it is the WAS version?

Comment: sorry for not answering for so long. we have always used WAS 6.1 (now it has FP 6.1.0.33 installed). this is how it looks for our application: http://s17.postimage.org/b2qjaurtb/2012_05_16_175155.jpg.